# UIWebView get favicons

Tags: ios, uiwebview

How can I get favicons from websites in ios UIWebView, like it is possible in android.
Maybe my question are idiotic, but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get favicon of any website using its url string.Lets take an example in which we're trying to get favicon of google :

```
NSString *myURLString = @"http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.stackoverflow.com";
NSURL *myURL=[NSURL URLWithString: myURLString];
NSData *myData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myURL];

UIImage *myImage=[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:myData];
```

This method of getting favicon worked nicely for me.

All the best.

Comment: But is any way how to get favicon in better quality?

Comment: it not working in all cases here is one http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=http://m.youtube.com